# Как добавить в Room database тип с помощью TypeConverter?

Tags: android, sqlite, mvvm, android-room

Имеются следующие data classы (основной с вложенными) с конструкторами по умолчанию в модели:

```
@Entity(tableName = "currentWeatherResponse")
data class CurrentWeatherResponse(
        @PrimaryKey
        val id:String= UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
        @Embedded
        val current: Current?=null,
        @Embedded
        val location: Location?=null,
        @Embedded
        val request: Request?=null
)

data class Current(

    val cloudcover: Int=0,
    val feelslike: Int=0,
    val humidity: Int=0,
    @SerializedName("is_day")
    val isDay: String= "",
    @SerializedName("observation_time")
    val observationTime: String= "",
    val precip: Float?=null,
    val pressure: Int=0,
    val temperature: Int=0,
    @SerializedName("uv_index")
    val uvIndex: Int=0,
    val visibility: Int=0,
    @SerializedName("weather_code")
    val weatherCode: Int=0,
    @SerializedName("weather_descriptions")
    val weatherDescriptions: List<String> = emptyList(),
    @SerializedName("weather_icons")
    val weatherIcons: List<String> = emptyList(),
    @SerializedName("wind_degree")
    val windDegree: Int=0,
    @SerializedName("wind_dir")
    val windDir: String="",
    @SerializedName("wind_speed")
    val windSpeed: Int=0
)


data class Location(
        val country: String= "",
        val lat: String= "",
        val localtime: String= "",
        @SerializedName("localtime_epoch")
        val localtimeEpoch: Int=0,
        val lon: String= "",
        val name: String= "",
        val region: String= "",
        @SerializedName("timezone_id")
        val timezoneId: String= "",
        @SerializedName("utc_offset")
        val utcOffset: String= ""
    )
data class Location(
    val country: String= "",
    val lat: String= "",
    val localtime: String= "",
    @SerializedName("localtime_epoch")
    val localtimeEpoch: Int=0,
    val lon: String= "",
    val name: String= "",
    val region: String= "",
    @SerializedName("timezone_id")
    val timezoneId: String= "",
    @SerializedName("utc_offset")
    val utcOffset: String= ""
)
```

Компилятор выдает следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Согласно документации https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data добавляю  TypeConverter с функциями для полей weatherDescriptions и weatherIcons:

```
import androidx.room.TypeConverter

    class Converters {
        @TypeConverter
        fun weatherDescriptionsToString(weatherDescriptions: List<String>?):String? {
            return weatherDescriptions?.get(0)!!.toString()
        }
        @TypeConverter
        fun weatherIconsToString(weatherIcons: List<String>?):String? {
            return weatherIcons?.get(0)?.toString()
        }
    }
```

Добавляю аннотацию в класс  Appdatabase и в databaseBuilder:

```
@Database(entities = [CurrentWeatherResponse::class], version = 4)
@TypeConverter(Converters::class)
abstract class RoomDB:RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun currentWeatherDAO(): CurrentWeatherDAO
}


class WeatherApp2: Application() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var repository: Repository
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, RoomDB::class.java, "db").addTypeConverter(Converters).build()

        repository = Repository(db)
    }
}
```

Далее IDE выдает следующее предупреждение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и также в билдере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы понять, что тут не хватает и требуется для передачи в Room?

Answer (score 2):

Аннотацией [@TypeConverter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/TypeConverter) маркируют методы конвертера.
А назначают конвертеры базе, сущностям и полям другой аннотацией: [@TypeConverter**s**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/TypeConverters)

```kotlin
@Database(entities = [CurrentWeatherResponse::class], version = 4)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class RoomDB:RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun currentWeatherDAO(): CurrentWeatherDAO
}
```

При добавлении конвертера через билдер базы нужно создать экземпляр:

```kotlin
val db = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, RoomDB::class.java, "db")
.addTypeConverter(Converters())
.build()
```

Comment: В билдере добавлять typeConverter нужно только для ProvidedTypeConverter, для которых требуется явно при создании передавать какие-то параметры. Для обычных статических конвертеров достаточно аннотации к базе (или явно для конкретных entity, dao и т.д.). https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data